# TSQL select max from 3 columns and then inner join a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, inner-join

How do I do this:

in table A I have 3 columns with integer values: a,b,c
in table B I have 3 columns with integer values: x,y,z

I want to select max of (a,b,c) and inner join the corresponding value from x,y,z.

Example:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

x = 7, y = 8, z = 9
```

result:
table with two columns

```
firstColumn  |  secondColumn

c            |  9
```

explanation: c is the max of a,b,c and we take the name, not the value
             9 is the value from the second table what we need

thanks in advance
ps I am using sql server 2014

Edit:  I tried to make an example with excel table

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question and the expected output?

Comment: @M.Ali Check out http://2.1m.yt/fefqfm.png I tried to make an example with excel table

Comment: You matching for the 2nd column based on _position_? SQL doesn't really do that outside of  a CASE statement for each possible position.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am matching a to x, b to y and c to z

Comment: You need a column in both tables that links the rows together. There is no concept of 1st or 2nd row in SQL (at least without an ordering criteria and nothing looks suitable)

Comment: Also: is there only one row in table B? I see how you want to match up which column to select, but not how you'll know which row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless both tables have only 1 row you'll propably don't want to do a CROSS JOIN that would join all records from table1 to all from table2.
So my guess is that you're looking for something like this:

```
select 
case 
when c > isnull(a,0) and c > isnull(b,0) then 'c'
when b > isnull(a,0) then 'b'
when a is not null then 'a'
end as firstColumn,
case
when c > isnull(a,0) and c > isnull(b,0) then z
when b > isnull(a,0) then y
when a is not null then x
end as secondColumn
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.table2_id = t2.id
```

Just a bit of test data:

```
declare @table1 table (id int identity(1,1), a int, b int, c int, table2_id int default 1);
declare @table2 table (id int, x int, y int, z int);
insert into @table1 (a, b, c) values
(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1),
(4,5,5),(5,4,5),(5,5,4),(4,5,4),(4,4,5),(4,4,4),
(6,7,null),(6,null,7),(null,6,7),
(8,null,null),(null,8,null),(null,null,8),(null,null,null);
insert into @table2 (id, x, y, z) values (1,100,200,300);
```

Answer (score 0):

The table structure you have shown us does not support your requirement. You need something that joins the rows in one table to the other.

If this exists you can then use ([demo](http://rextester.com/HRQ47276))

```
SELECT t1label,
       t2col
FROM   TableA TA
       JOIN TableB TB
         ON TA.rownum = TB.rownum
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   (VALUES('A', TA.a, TB.x),
                                  ('B', TA.b, TB.y),
                                  ('C', TA.c, TB.z)) v(t1label, t1col, t2col)
                    ORDER  BY t1col DESC) CA
```

In the event a TableA  row has two or more columns with the same maximum value it is undeterministic which will be selected.